# AMX Glassfish AppserverConnectionSource

Tags: glassfish-3

I am able to connect Glassfish AS 3.1 via JMX with the following URL
service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:8686/jmxrmi

However I could not connect it via AMX. Here is the API I am using

> amx-api-10.0-SNAPSHOT

I have realized in its source code that url is defined different than the following one. It is defined in class AppserverConnectionSource.java

```
private static final String APPSERVER_JNDI_NAME = "/management/rmi-jmx-connector";
```

When I try to connect AS AMX interface I am getting the following error.

> Connecting using JMXServiceURL: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:8686/management/rmi-jmx-connector
>   java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: management/rmi-jmx-connector
>       at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:338)
>       at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:248)
>       at com.sun.appserv.management.client.AppserverConnectionSource.createNew(AppserverConnectionSource.java:412)
>       at com.sun.appserv.management.client.AppserverConnectionSource.getJMXConnector(AppserverConnectionSource.java:481)
>       at com.sun.appserv.management.client.AppserverConnectionSource.getMBeanServerConnection(AppserverConnectionSource.java:513)
>       at com.sun.appserv.management.client.ProxyFactory.getInstance(ProxyFactory.java:399)
>       at com.sun.appserv.management.client.ProxyFactory.getInstance(ProxyFactory.java:373)
>       at com.sun.appserv.management.client.AppserverConnectionSource.getDomainRoot(AppserverConnectionSource.java:528)

Answer (score 0):

Too little to late I know but I can't resist. I have had the same issue and recreating the node instance doesn't do the trick. I looked into my node logs and found I was missing jars. Simply by adding those missing jars I was able to start the cluster with its node instance again.